# Problems with Python - Installing Modules

Tags: python, cmd, installation, pip, easy-install

Had a friend write some script for me. After about an hour, he declared himself one working on it and sent it to me to complete. So I downloaded Python27 and have been tying to get my head in the game.

My friend used some extra modules in his program and I need to get those up and running before I can see the code running.I've tried following [several instructionals](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/) with no success.

So I was hoping for some help. My Python directory is where it should be in C:\Python27. I've been trying to use the Python )command line) in order to input the code as given and i keep getting back the same result.

"File " line 1
$pip install requests

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am completely lost and starting to get a headache. Please help!

Comment: `pip` is a command that you run on your operating system command line (e.g., the "DOS prompt"), not from inside Python.

Answer (score 0):

'pip' is a command line program, not a python construct.

Try [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)
first to get the pip command on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use python command line interpreter to install the package.

First, follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1) to install pip on Windows. Then you can directly put the `pip install` command in your cmd.exe and execute it.